# Improve "Thanks for the feedback" popup when not signed in

Tags: feature-request, popups, post-feedback, anonymous-visitors

I was exploring an SE community I'm not a part of and got this message pressing the downvote button (on a not-answer) without thinking:

[image: Thanks for the feedback!]

The first issue I have with it is repetition. It says ***Setting up an account***, then ***Set up your account today*** in the next sentence.

Also, it gives a weird vibe of *free* to get account, but *pay* to get features (reputation), like several (not) free sites. SE is a free site and shouldn't have that vibe (it was also complained about before in the new users intro, but I can't find the link).

My suggestion is to replace the popup message with a small blue box (like the "You must have XX reputation to _____" message when you are signed in) under the button that says "You must be signed in and have XX reputation to _____".

Comment: What you suggest was in place in the past, until they added the post feedback feature. For more details, read [this answer by Shog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326060/change-the-wording-of-thank-you-for-your-feedback-when-a-user-below-125-re/327213#327213).